# Trying to connect to EC2 instance in private subnet from bastion server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have 2 EC2 instances - one is in a private subnet connected to a nat gateway and the other is in a public subnet connected to an internet gateway. I have a jenkins server on the private subnet and a bastion server in the public subnet.

I used scp to copy the pem key used when creating my jenkins instance over to my bastion server and am now trying to connect to the jenkins instance via the bastion.

I run the command `ssh -i pem.key ubuntu@privateipaddress` but keep getting a permission denied (publickey) error.

I've checked my security group settings for both instances and they check out. The inbound rules  for the jenkins security group allow SSH and HTTP traffic from the bastion security group and the outbound rules for the jenkins security group currently allow all traffic through.

I have the reverse for the bastion security group.

EDIT: Verbose:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.1.49 [10.0.1.49] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.1.49:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EgAjWBAxVLz8L+MQNQXZeIwh51QZOPxPhvugsxv1XGs
debug1: Host '10.0.1.49' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: key.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@10.0.1.49: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: If you are getting that error then it doesn't sound like a security group issue. Try adding `-v` to the `ssh` command to get more verbose output.

Comment: I edited the question to include the verbose output

Comment: Where is this "key.pem" file stored?

Comment: i used scp to copy it over to the bastion. It's in the .ssh folder on that instance

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by following this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/

I had come across it before, but never considered trying because a trainer on my course said I wouldn't need to.

Comment: For your first approach using the ssh agent was not needed, why that has not worked relies surely somewhere else, user name correct, key file is the correct one? But anyway forwarding ssh keys is the better approach. Uploading your private key to a bastion host is not recommended as anyone having access to the instance can take it!